# Calling a static model function from a controller in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am trying to set a default value for select box in CakePHP. My options are accessed using a static function in the model which is defined like so

```
public static function purpose($value = null)
{
    $options = array(
        self::PURPOSE_HOMECONSUMPTION => __('Home Consumption', true),
        self::PURPOSE_COMMERCIAL => __('Commercial', true)
    );
    return self::enum($value, $options);
}

// Constants for status attribute
const PURPOSE_HOMECONSUMPTION = '0';
const PURPOSE_COMMERCIAL = '1';
```

In my view, I fill the select box by calling this static function in this manner

```
echo $this->Form->input('purpose', array(
  'type' => 'select',
  'options' => Field::purpose()
```

Sure enough it picks the options but the default value is `Home Consumption`. I want to set it `Commercial`.  I tried something like this in the controller

```
$this->request->data['Field']['purpose'] = Field::purpose(1);
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas about how i can call the static function in the controller with the value set to `Commercial`.

Comment: Looks like my static enums.. :P

Comment: why not using the `default` option for the input?

Comment: @arilia Default values (coming from the model layer) IMO are part of the logic IMO and should be in the else clause of the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using class constants and then NOT using them in the code?
Makes no sense to me.

You are on top resolving the integer value into the string. That also does not make sense if you want to use it as default value for a dropdown populated with your enum data.

The correct approach, logically, would be:

```
// The constant that holds the value 1
$this->request->data['Field']['purpose'] = ModelName::PURPOSE_COMMERCIAL;
```

Also note that constants should best be real integers, and you should be using tinyint(2) for the db type as mentioned on the blog code.

Comment: No the request data option will not work because it will be empty. The trick would be setting the default while being able to retrieve the options list.  I am not sure how to do this correctly?

Comment: Using the above approach. You can't call the `ModelName` because it will say class not found.  Anyway am not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: the request data option is correct but for some reason it could not load the model class so  I used `$this->loadModel('Field')` though it doesn't make sense since am in the field controller.

Comment: Of couse you need to always include all classes you (statically) use or initialize. So in your case you missed the essential (CakePHP basics) `App::uses('ModelName', 'Model')` in your controller file call above your class.